# Node.JS: writing to child process spawn after receiving stdout data

Tags: javascript, node.js, io, child-process

**What I am trying to do:** I've written a chess engine in c++ that I've compiled into an executable. I am now using Node.JS to let this engine communicate with a chess website's API (so that humans and other engines can challenge it).

I am using Node.JS's `child_process` module to create a `spawn` that will facilitate I/O communication between the API and the engine.

In order to tell the engine that a new game has started, I write `"UCI\n"` to the process. I then wait for the engine to output `"id name {engine name}\r\nid author {my name}\r\nuciok\r\n"`. After I receive this output from my engine, I then need to write `"isready\n"` back to it so that it can start generating moves later on.

**My problem:** The problem I am facing is that, after my initial `"UCI\n"` write to the process, I call `child_process.spawn().stdin.end()`. It seems that this `end()` call has to exist somewhere, or else I am my process doesn't pick up on the input I am writing to it.

Whenever I try to write `"isready\n"` to the child process after receiving the engine's output, I am hit with this error:

> Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end

The whole thing looks something like this:

```js
const engineExePath = 'C:\\Users\\chopi\\Desktop\\chess-engine\\maestro\\uci.exe';
const childProcess = require('child_process');
const spawn_options = {
    cwd: null, env: null, detached: false
}

const engineStream = childProcess.spawn(engineExePath, [], spawn_options);
engineStream.stdout.on('data', function (data) {

    var result = data.toString();

    if (result == 'id name Maestro\r\nid author dvdutch\r\nuciok\r\n') {
        //Here, we are listening to the response from the engine, and are now ready to spit back a message to it.
        //This is where the error is occurring
        engineStream.stdin.write('isready\n');
    } else {
        console.log('no match');
    }

});

engineStream.stdin.write('uci\n');
engineStream.stdin.end();
```

**What I've tried:** I've tried to call `engineStream.stdin.end()` when the child process closes its stream via:

```js
engineStream.on('close', (code) => {
  engineStream.stdin.end();
});
```

However, when I do this, it seems no communication whatsoever is facilitated between my Node file and my child process, sort of like when `engineStream.stdin.end()` simply doesn't get called whatsoever. The whole integration with this method would look something like this:

```js
const engineExePath = 'C:\\Users\\chopi\\Desktop\\chess-engine\\maestro\\uci.exe';
const childProcess = require('child_process');
const spawn_options = {
    cwd: null, env: null, detached: false
}

const engineStream = childProcess.spawn(engineExePath, [], spawn_options);
engineStream.stdout.on('data', function (data) {

    var result = data.toString();

    if (result == 'id name Maestro\r\nid author dvdutch\r\nuciok\r\n') {
        //Here, we are listening to the response from the engine, and are now ready to spit back a message to it.
        engineStream.stdin.write('isready\n');
    } else {
        console.log('no match');
    }

});

engineStream.on('close', (code) => {
  engineStream.stdin.end();
});

engineStream.stdin.write('uci\n');
```

**What I'm wondering:**
What is the correct way to facilitate this ping-ponging of messages between my child process and my Node file?

Comment: Does it work when sending `echo uci` to `cmd` instead of your process?  Also `data` is not guaranteed to be lines. input is buffered into chunks.

Comment: Running `uci.exe` and then typing `echo uci` from `cmd` does not return anything. However, I have installed the engine executable on a chess engine GUI (that communicates moves made from the user via the GUI to the engine and moves from the engine back to the user) and it works fine there.

Comment: Sorry I meant node spawning `cmd` instead of `uci.exe`. i.e. checking if another windows process performs the way you want `uci.exe` to or is it a general platform issue writing to stdin from node.

Comment: From a quick test it looks like a spawned `cmd` can pick up the input on the next js tick without using `.end()`

Comment: You're right, spawning `cmd.exe` and echoing some stuff back, listening for the echo, and writing again allows me to write multiple times. This requires me to remove `engineStream.stdin.end()`, of course. Since `cmd.exe` is able to do this just fine, I'll look into reasons why omitting this line would prevent `uci.exe` from spitting any output out to my node file.

Comment: Of course, I go back and remove `engineStream.stdin.end()` and everything is working the way I expect it. I'm not sure what's different from my configuration before. And I was about to bounty this too ‍♂️. Anyways, thanks for the help @Matt !